# This what I get in GGTS what to do to resolve it?

Tags: grails, gradle

When I try to debug my code it shows the below error in GGTS, how can I resolve it?

```
    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    :: org.grails.plugins#code-coverage;1.1.7: not found
    :: org.grails.plugins#tomcat;1.3.1: not found
    :: org.grails.plugins#hibernate;1.3.1: not found
    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

| Error Failed to resolve dependencies 
(Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):
- org.grails.plugins:code-coverage:1.1.7
- org.grails.plugins:tomcat:1.3.1
- org.grails.plugins:hibernate:1.3.1
```

Comment: Which version of Grails? Are you using gradle?

Comment: can you post your plugin dependencies in `application.properties` and `BuildConfig.groovy`?

Comment: "This is application.properties"app.grails.version=1.3.1
app.name=elements
app.servlet.version=2.4
app.version=0.9.8
plugins.code-coverage=1.1.7
plugins.hibernate=1.3.1
plugins.tomcat=1.3.1

Comment: BuildConfig.groovy is given below

Comment: Thisis my BuildConfig.groovy file


grails.project.class.dir = 'target/classes'
grails.project.test.class.dir = 'target/test-classes'
grails.project.test.reports.dir = 'target/test-reports'
grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"
codenarc.reportName = 'target/CodeNarcReport.html'
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
 inherits "global" // inherit Grails' default dependencies
 repositories {
  grailsHome()
 }
 plugins {
  compile ":wcommon:1.0"
  compile ":hibernate:1.3.1"
  compile ":codenarc:0.6.1"
 }
}

Comment: Remaining part of file is: coverage {
 enabledByDefault = true
 xml = true
 exclusions = [
  'com/wingu/common/**',
  'org/**',
  '*Config*.*'
 ]
 sourceInclusions = ['grails-app/conf', 'grails-app/jobs']
}

Comment: You don't seem to be using Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Did you just upgrade your grails version?

Grails changed a bit how it handles tomcat and hibernate versions.

In your BuildConfig.groovy, replace your tomcat line by `build ":tomcat:7.0.47"`; and your hibernate line by `runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.6" // or ":hibernate4:4.1.11.6"`

Comment: I havent understood where to specify it exactly. BCZ inside buildConfig.groovy i cnt find a line for tomcat

Comment: remaining part of file is

Comment: Oh, ok, then you should probably add it.